# mod_rewrite keep referrer by rewriting to https

Tags: mod-rewrite, ssl, https, http-referer

I redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with mod_rewrite.
The HTTP_REFERER header is lost and my analyse tool can not recognize from where my users came from.

```
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```

How can I keep the referer with this redirection?

My application has only HTTPS pages and no HTTP direct access.

Comment: I think this is a security feature of browsers, so no way of fixing that. You could however add the referrer as a parameter to redirect url. So e.g `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R=301]`

Comment: this did not work.... the referer should remain in HTTP header to work. Wondering why this isn't supported by mod_rewrite.

Comment: Because this isn't a server thing, but a browser thing.